# RaphaelJS display only one active state

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

**Update:**

I've fixed up my referencing below, and my problem is now more specific.

Background: I've got a set paths making up a map. Currently I have a visual on/off state when each region is clicked on, but I only want one region 'active' at any given time. I am calling a function which is meant to loop through all the regions, and change the fill colour of any non-active regions back to grey. Currently it seems to create a new set of paths when the following line is run: `var obj = rsr.path(pathObj.path);`. Below is a screen of the before and after.

[image: The default state of the map]

[image: What happens when the map is clicked]

I know this isn't a rendering issue as the new paths are injected into the DOM.

This is my last hurdle on this project, I feel I'm so close!

You can view the page here: http://ochrerecruitment.com.s145292.gridserver.com/job-search/

This is the function I am running at the end of the click event (courtesy of Eliran Malka, thank you):

```
function onlyOneRegion() {
    for (var state in paths) {
            var pathObj = paths[state];
            var obj = rsr.path(pathObj.path);
            if (pathObj.active) {
                // do something
            } else {
                pathObj.active = false;
                obj.toFront();
                obj.animate({
                    fill: attributes.fill,
                    scale: 1,
                    'stroke' : '#fff',
                    'stroke-width' : 1,
                    transform: 's1'
                }, 150);
            }
    };
}
```

Thanks again!

**Original Question:**

I've currently got a map that sets a `<select>` value when clicked. Each region on the map also has a hover state and an on/off state.

The `<select>` functionality only allows one region to be active at any given time.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to visually display only one active item. So on click, a region turns on, but I also want it to turn all other regions off.

My full function can be viewed here: http://pastie.org/3675997

The structure of each region is as follows:

```
var paths = {
    southisland: {
        name: 'southisland',
        path: 'coords',
        active: 'false'
    }
```

in my click event I have the following if else:

```
if (this.active) {
    this.active = false;
    this.animate({
        fill: attributes.fill,
        scale: '1',
        'stroke-width' : '1',
        transform: 's1'
    }, 150);                    
} else {
    this.active = true;
    this.animate({
        fill: '#e36f1e',
        scale: '1',
        'stroke-width' : '1',
        transform: 's1'
    }, 150);
}
```

straight after that I am trying to call the following function:

```
function onlyOneRegion() {
    for (var state in paths) {
        var obj = rsr.path(paths[state].path);
        if (state[active]) {
        } else {
            state[active] = false;

            obj.animate({
                fill: attributes.fill,
                scale: '1',
                'stroke-width' : '1',
                transform: 's1'
            }, 150);
        }
    };
}
```

This function doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't work wither.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the updated issue by rewriting my map creation into a function. Each time the a region is clicked on, It remembers that region, the deletes and re-creates the map, matching up the region with the relevant state id and making it active. Not the most elegant solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Can you possibly share the code I'm trying to achieve the same thing and can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to call a property on the `paths` index. note that `state` is the index of the `paths` list iterator, not an object (as in Java for-each iterations, for example).

another thing, when passing numeric values, pass them as numeric values (not as strings).

try to correct your function like so:

```
function onlyOneRegion() {
    for (var state in paths) {
        var pathObj = paths[state];
        var obj = rsr.path(pathObj.path);

        if (pathObj.active]) {
            // do something
        } else {
            pathObj.active = false;

            obj.animate({
                fill: attributes.fill,
                scale: 1,
                'stroke-width' : 1,
                transform: 's1'
            }, 150);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems that whenever I call rsr.path, it creates a new instance of the path. You can view it in action here: ochrerecruitment.com.s145292.gridserver.com/job-search

Answer (score 0):

please replace this `state[active]` with `state['active']`

also replace `state[active]` with `paths[state]['active']` as `state` is string - the name of the state

Comment: Thanks. Unforunately it comes up as undefined in my console.log, although console.log(state) parses fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your full paste you're not actually calling `onlyOneRegion()` anywhere. You'll need to add a call to it somewhere inside your `click()`.

Also note that '`this`' inside `onlyOneRegion()` won't be correct (I guess you'll see what's going on there when you get the function working, it'll need to be `rsr.path(paths[state].path)`).

Comment: Cheers. I'm currently calling it straight after the if else mentioned above (sorry the pastie is about 30min older than the stack question ;) )

Comment: Ah right! That should work. Have you replaced the 'this' with rsr.path(paths[state].path) or something similar? It should at least be throwing an error if not.

Comment: Its a weird one. state['name'], state['active'] etc are coming back undefined in my onlyOneRegion function. One the onlyOneRegion function runs it freezes any further interaction but doesn't throw an error

Comment: Oh, you actually want `paths[state].active` there.

Comment: Thanks Huw – I'm nearly there. FYI this is the test link: http://ochrerecruitment.com.s145292.gridserver.com/job-search
Currently it seems that when I call rsr.path(paths[state]['path']), it creates a new instances of each region :S